# How to block URL pattern using Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, web2py

I have a web2py application run under Apache via mod_wsgi.  **How do I restrict access to the admin page (www.myapp.com/admin) based on source IP?**

Ideally, I do it directly within Apache for two reasons: 1) I assume that Apache has more effective access to the source IP [citation needed] and 2) I don't feel like modifying the stock admin page in web2py to block specific IPs.

My (abridged) configuration looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=myapp group=myapp
  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myapp/myapp/wsgihandler.py

  TimeOut 45

  ServerName myapp.com
  ServerAlias www.myapp.com


  <Directory /home/myapp/myapp>

    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all

    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Allow from all
    </Files>

  </Directory>

  #======================================
  # THIS IS WHAT I TRIED THAT DIDN'T WORK
  <Directory /home/myapp/myapp/admin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Directory>
  #======================================

  AliasMatch ^/static/(.*) \
           /home/myapp/myapp/applications/myapp/static/$1
  <Directory /home/myapp/myapp/applications/myapp/static/>
    Options -Indexes 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # HTTPS enforcement
  # Out of convenience, forward /a* to https, covers /admin /appadmin and /a (front facing admin)
  RedirectMatch ^/a(.*) https://myapp.com/a$1
  RedirectMatch ^/c/(.*) https://myapp.com/c/$1
  RedirectMatch ^/w/user/login(?:/(.*)|$) https://myapp.com/w/user/login/$1
  RedirectMatch ^/w/user/register(?:/(.*)|$) https://myapp.com/w/user/register/$1

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I have a similar VirtualHost for port 443.  I just didn't include it for the sake of redundancy.

Normally, it is my understanding that I could use something like the directory notation to deny access to certain directories.  However, the above didn't work and I wonder if it has to do with the WSGIScriptAlias directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<Location /admin>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Comment: Where? He doesn't use the Location directive at all. The Directory directive takes a file system path but that will not work in this case. It has to be the Location directive and the sub URL.

Comment: Will test shortly and accept if it works out.  Definitely didn't know about the differences between Directory and Location directives!